# Widget is taking maximum space in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some widgets (message bubbles ) inside a StreamBuilder, however this message bubbles are taking the maximum space possible when they should adapt to the size of the text inside.
This is the code of the main screen:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              List<Widget> messagesWidgets = [];
              if (snapshot.hasData){
                final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
                for (var message in messages){
                  final messageText = message.data()['text'];
                  final messageSender = message.data()['sender'];

                  final messageWidget = MessageBubble(
                    text: messageText,
                    sender: messageSender,
                  );
                  messagesWidgets.add(messageWidget);
                }
              }

              return Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 20.0),
                  children: messagesWidgets,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          Container(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
               Expanded(
                 flex: 6,
                 child: TextInput(
                   textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                   onChanged: (value){
                      messageText = value;
                   },
                   hintText: 'Type a message',
                 ),
               ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Button(
                    child: Icon(Icons.send, color: background,),
                    function: (){
                      if(messageText.trim() == '') return;
                      _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                        'text': messageText,
                        'sender': Usr.email,
                      });
                      setState(() {
                        messageText = '';
                      });
                    },
                    tag: 'hey2d2',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

And this is the code of the message bubbles:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
        child: Material(
          elevation: 10.0,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          color: Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    '$sender',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: background,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                      '$text',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      color: background,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Here there is a screenshot of what I mean:
[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `ListView` widget automatically forces its children to take up all the available width. You can bypass this behaviour by wrapping the message bubble container with the `Align` widget. See below:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Align(
    // Set the align's alignment to centerLeft.
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    child: Container(
      ...
    ),
  );
}
```